# Триггер в xaml не обновляет свойство ViewModel (WPF)

Tags: wpf

В xaml имею Listbox,
его ItemsSource является ObservableCollection
его SelectedItem является элемент из данной коллекции
Также имеется триггер, отлавливающий наведение мыши на элемент Listbox и по моим представлениям он должен делать этот элемент выбранным, но этого не происходит, свойство, привязанное к SelectedItem  не изменяет свое значение при наведении мыши.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 6"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

В общем прошу помощи, как сделать, чтобы при наведении мыши, в свойство SelectedItem  записывался объект из коллекции, на который наведена мышь.
Спасибо!

Comment: В общем путем проб и ошибок выяснилось, что при наведении мыши на элемент Listbox(когда срабатывает триггер) - если нажать на него ЛКМ, то в привязанное свойство SelectedItem  уходит null по невыясненной причине. Пока придумал только в сеттер данного свойства поставить защиту от null.....  if (value != null)